# Laravel upsert operations with Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

In one of the my worker scripts to store aggregate counts based on some metrics, I am not using Eloquent as the queries are a little complex and and it is easy to write using query builder. I am currently getting the values from the database and I need to insert/update it in the database. Can an upsert operation is possible by using the save() method can be achieved using Query Builder? Or do I need to check every time whether this entry is in database?

I have a total of 100,000 entries and would like to run it as a daily job. So if I need to check whether a particular entry is there in DB, I need to access the database that many times. Is there an alternative solution for this ?

I am thinking about creating two model classes, one using Eloquent and one using query builder. Can I use my custom query in the Eloquent model?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Now (Oct 6, 2020), Laravel(v8.10.0) has native `upsert` support. https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/34698

The first argument is the values to insert/update and the second argument is the column(s) that uniquely identify records. All databases except SQL Server require these columns to have a PRIMARY or UNIQUE index.

```
DB::table('users')->upsert([
    ['id' => 1, 'email' => 'taylor@example.com'],
    ['id' => 2, 'email' => 'dayle@example.com'],
], 'email');
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this. I have asked the question 4 years before.

Comment: How can we get the inserted ids?

Comment: @HappyCoder No matter how old the question is if you have something to say. It would help someone who stumbled upon your question.

Comment: Will it only work when there is a unique index applied to the column? @baijunyao

Answer (score 15):

Eloquent has `updateOrCreate()` method which allows you to do exactly want you want. But Query Builder doesn't have similar method.

You can build raw query with Query Builder and use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) as upsert solution.

Comment: Be aware `updateOrCreate` is not as atomic as SQL upsert: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/2656d7a7118a6d9fe1f8c9ed22d65ab609b8ae1d/Eloquent/Builder.php#L391. It selects first, then insert or update, which can be prone to race conditions.

Comment: Note: Insert ... on duplicate key ... is MySQL Syntax.  Other RDBMS will have similar functionality but with different syntax. [Postgres for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: I've created an UPSERT package for all databases: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert

Answer (score 4):

Eloquent has the method called `updateOrCreate`, which can be used like this example:

```php
<?
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    [
       'code' => '156787', 
       'destination' => 'COL'
    ],
    [
       'code' => '156787', 
       'destination' => 'COL',
       'price' => 99, 
       'discounted' => 1,
    ],
);
```

1. Search by `code` and `destination` could by your best to identify your rows.
2. It creates or updates according to the values given in the second array.

The following is the sign of the method.

```
/**
 * Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 */
public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```